# caching of Google Places API results

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm building a mobile app that lists posts, each post has a place attached to it.

I want the list to be able to show distance from the user's location.
without caching anything it would require to store the place reference for each post and while listing fetch the place's geometry from Google Places API, this sounds like a very bad idea.

am I allowed to store the place's id, reference, name and geometry in my db and deliver it with my API?
this is for performance purposes only

another implementation might be to cache this data in a local sqlite db on the mobile device, but then the user will have to download the information for each uncached place so for a list of X different places the client will be doing X api calls, sounds slow and battery wasting.

am I allowed to have a central cache in my db in a table that'll be refreshed every once in a while and evicted if not accessed for lets say 30 days ?

Comment: Encourage you to read section 10.1.3b of the Google Maps API TOS: http://goo.gl/8drnj

Comment: I read it, what is a good caching strategy for mobile app that lists distances from current location ? fetch the lat/lon information for each list item for every client may result in an insane number of requests

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Google's page on Places](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/policies#pre-fetching_caching_or_storage_of_content) states that Caching of the Places ID is allowed.

The [terms in 10.5.d](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5) state that you may store *limited* amounts of content for no more than 30 calendar days for *performance reasons*. Since this is what you are trying to do, then I would expect that you are ok to store the ID, location and name.

As you start to cache more information then you'll breach the terms of the API. It's not too clear what these are but I think as long as you are being *reasonable* then you'll be OK.

Comment: That was from the Feb 7, 2108 license. As of March 2019, it's now under 3.2.4 a Restrictions Against Misusing the Services which states, "Caching is permitted for certain Services as described in the Maps Service Specific Terms." Tracking that down you can store the `place_id`, and cache the lat/long for 30 days.

Comment: I can't find those numbers in the links in the answer anymore. Here is the fresh one: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms/maps-service-terms/

>5.4 Caching. Customer can temporarily cache latitude (lat) and longitude (lng) values from the Places API for up to 30 consecutive calendar days, after which Customer must delete the cached latitude and longitude values. Customer can cache Places API Place ID (place_id) values, in accordance with the Places API Policies.

Comment: Can I then after 30 days, refresh the lat/lng? Or I need to delete permanently?

Comment: @teebo Yes you can refresh them.

Answer (score 9):

As per the current policy, the Place Id is exempt from the caching restriction.

[Pre-Fetching, Caching or Storage of contents](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/policies)

> Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content Applications using the
>   Directions API are bound by the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service.
>   Section 3.2.4(a) of the terms states that you must not pre-fetch,
>   cache, index, or store any Content except under the limited conditions
>   stated in the terms.
>
> Note that the place ID, used to uniquely identify a place, is exempt
>   from the caching restriction. You can therefore store place ID values
>   indefinitely. Place ID values are returned in the place_id field in
>   Directions API responses.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the one from @Curly is outdated, unfortunately!

Comment: "...except under the limited conditions stated in the terms." I went through all of the Google's latest terms and it is still not clear under what conditions I can store more data like place name, address, etc. Could somebody help here please?

Answer (score 1):

"Note that the place ID, used to uniquely identify a place, is exempt from the caching restriction. You can therefore store place ID values indefinitely. The place ID is returned in the place_id field in Places API responses." https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies#usage_limits