# Intelligently cache google places

Tags: google-maps, caching, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm attempting to build a multiplayer GPS game that uses Google Places to retrieve local places, such as stores or other points of interest. I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10837048/caching-of-google-places-api-results) that it might be a bit difficult to straight-up cache all of the information I get, but at the same time, I'm concerned I'll hit my API limits very quickly, so I'm looking for an intermediate solution.

I'm trying to come up with a way to intelligently cache google places. Supposing there was only one player per city, they could wander around and discover things and possibly not have any problems if I were to just keep asking google for data every so often. My base case for hitting google would be "you logged in, there are zero places around you, lets get some from google" and my update case would be "you traveled a certain distance from your start location, lets get some more data around you"

However, when two players start in opposite sides of the city, that's a bit trickier. If I were to cache results that I would find, I might possibly miss some points of interest. Suppose that P2 starts on the very outside of the circle of where the P1 has been; that means P2 would not get any data elsewhere because they already have some data (because follow the previous algorithm, P1 has already explored this area, so when P2 logs in, P2 does not need to query google to get more data). It would be difficult to know if I had something cached already, as well, without querying google and then checking the database.

Are there any good strategies to overcoming a situation like this?

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation on the downvote(s).

Comment: I'd suggest removing the bonus question, that is off topic as it is a legal question and not a programming one and may have attracted the downvote. Also you question is rather broad and has already attracted a close vote for that.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I've removed the bonus question. Honestly, I don't know how to make it more specific... I feel like I was pretty clear; no one has told me what they see as unclear so it's pretty hard to fix it.

Comment: Did you try caching the place IDs?

Comment: @not_a_bot I plan to do that, but my question is more one of "how do I know if I should update from google places" without actually hitting google places (I'm trying to figure out how to best utilize my limited quota).

Comment: Cache now....wait 30 days....fetch and cache again https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Comment: Yeah but that will only give 'place_id' which is of no use. I need places names as well :(